# How can I use Python / pyodbc to push data to Google Sheets?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

Upfront: I'm extremely new to Python. : )

I have taken Google's [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) information, and can successfully connect to my Google Sheet with read/write privilege and clear the sheet for any previous information. Also, I was able to follow the [pyodbc docs](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc), and can successfully connect to a MSSQL server that we utilize and write out an Excel copy of the MSSQL table.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to get the table MSSQL query results appended to the Google Sheet. Within VSCode, it does provide the most recent call in the traceback, and it does appear to be working correctly with no errors. However, the sheet doesn't get updated.

Note: If I change the value for `dfListFormat`to a text string, it does append that single value in A1 of the target range.

```
value_range_body = {
        "majorDimension": "ROWS",
        "values": [
            [dfListFormat]
        ]
    }
```

Below is the full code I currently have. Any help/advice you all could provide would be greatly appreciated.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import oauth2client
import os
import googleapiclient
import openpyxl
import pandas
import pyodbc

from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from openpyxl import Workbook
from pandas import DataFrame, ExcelWriter


""" This is the code to get raw data from a specific Google Sheet"""
try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret_noemail.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Sheets API Python'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json')

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else:  # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.

    Creates a Sheets API service object and prints the names and majors of
    students in a sample spreadsheet:
    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
    """
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    discoveryUrl = ('https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4')
    service = discovery.build(
        'sheets', 'v4', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=discoveryUrl)

    # Google Sheet Url Link and Range name. Can use tab names to get full page.
    spreadsheetId = '[spreadsheetid]'
    rangeName = 'tblActiveEmployees'

    # TODO: Add desired entries to the request body if needed
    clear_values_request_body = {}

    # Building Service to Clear Google Sheet
    request = service.spreadsheets().values().clear(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId,
                                                    range=rangeName, body=clear_values_request_body)
    response = request.execute()

    # Prints response that Google Sheet has been cleared
    responseText = '\n'.join(
        [str(response), 'The Google Sheet has been cleared!'])
    print(responseText)

    # SQL Server Connection
    server = '[SQLServerIP]'
    database = '[SQLServerDB]'
    username = '[SQLServerUserID]'
    password = '[SQLServerPW]'
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=' +
                          server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+password)

    # Sample SQL Query to get Data
    sql = 'select * from tblActiveEmployees'
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    list(cursor.fetchall())

    # Pandas reading values from SQL query, and building table
    sqlData = pandas.read_sql_query(sql, cnxn)

    # Pandas building dataframe, and exporting .xlsx copy of table
    df = DataFrame(data=sqlData)

    df.to_excel('tblActiveEmployees.xlsx',
                header=True, index=False)
    dfListFormat = df.values.tolist()

    # How the input data should be interpreted.
    value_input_option = 'USER_ENTERED'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

    # How the input data should be inserted.
    insert_data_option = 'OVERWRITE'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

    value_range_body = {
        "majorDimension": "ROWS",
        "values": [
            [dfListFormat]
        ]
    }

    request = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName,
                                                     valueInputOption=value_input_option, insertDataOption=insert_data_option, body=value_range_body)
    response = request.execute()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You're importing from both `apiclient` and `googleapiclient`? I would think you only need to use `googleapiclient`...  Re: your issue, have you printed out / inspected what the `"values":` property is with your data? Seems like that is your issue, as it should be [an array of arrays](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/python/latest/sheets_v4.spreadsheets.values.html#append).

Comment: Ahh, yeah... the API Quickstart uses the apiclient, and I also saw that googleapiclient is the newer version? Good catch. Yes, per your suggestion, I printed out the results and saw they were already in an array. Attempting to run the .py with the [] removed around the values section worked perfectly. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @tehhowch's input, the following was able to solve my problem. The issue was that my data was already in a list, and using it as `"values": [[dfListFormat]]` made `"values"` an array of an array of arrays, rather than just an array of arrays. Simply assigning to `"values"` without brackets worked perfectly.

Below is the updated code, and big thanks to tehhowch!

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import oauth2client
import os
import googleapiclient
import openpyxl
import pandas
import pyodbc

from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from openpyxl import Workbook
from pandas import DataFrame, ExcelWriter


""" This is the code to get raw data from a specific Google Sheet"""
try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret_noemail.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Sheets API Python'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json')

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else:  # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.

    Creates a Sheets API service object and prints the names and majors of
    students in a sample spreadsheet:
    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
    """
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    discoveryUrl = ('https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4')
    service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        'sheets', 'v4', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=discoveryUrl)

    # Google Sheet Url Link and Range name. Can use tab names to get full page.
    spreadsheetId = '[spreadsheetID'
    rangeName = 'tblActiveEmployees'

    # TODO: Add desired entries to the request body if needed
    clear_values_request_body = {}

    # Building Service to Clear Google Sheet
    request = service.spreadsheets().values().clear(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId,
                                                    range=rangeName, body=clear_values_request_body)
    response = request.execute()

    # Prints response that Google Sheet has been cleared
    responseText = '\n'.join(
        [str(response), 'The Google Sheet has been cleared!'])
    print(responseText)

    # SQL Server Connection
    server = '[SQLServerIP]'
    database = '[SQLServerDB]'
    username = '[SQLServerUserID]'
    password = '[SQLServerPW]'
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=' +
                          server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+password)

    # Sample SQL Query to get Data
    sql = 'select * from tblActiveEmployees'
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    list(cursor.fetchall())

    # Pandas reading values from SQL query, and building table
    sqlData = pandas.read_sql_query(sql, cnxn)

    # Pandas building dataframe, and exporting .xlsx copy of table
    df = DataFrame(data=sqlData)

    df.to_excel('tblActiveEmployees.xlsx',
                header=True, index=False)
    dfHeaders = df.columns.values.tolist()
    dfHeadersArray = [dfHeaders]
    dfData = df.values.tolist()

    print(dfHeaders)
    print(dfData)

    # How the input data should be interpreted.
    value_input_option = 'USER_ENTERED'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

    # How the input data should be inserted.
    insert_data_option = 'OVERWRITE'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

    value_range_body = {
        "majorDimension": "ROWS",
        "values": dfHeadersArray + dfData
    }

    request = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName,
                                                     valueInputOption=value_input_option, insertDataOption=insert_data_option, body=value_range_body)
    response = request.execute()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: So, just so I'm understanding this correctly, are you reading a sql query into a df and pushing that into a Google sheet? If so that's bloody awesome will give it a shot!

Comment: Hey @Datanovice, yes! That's right. I'm able to read directly from our MSSQL server, and post to Google Sheets. It's been working great!